# Generate random variables from some PDF

Tags: random-variables, self-learning, sampling, monte-carlo

My problem is the following. I am given a PDF, say $p(x) = x \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-x}$ for $x > 0$. I want to generate $n$, say $n = 1000$, random variables given this density, such that I can calculate the probability that the $Y = X_{1} + \cdots + X_{n} > \gamma$ where $\gamma$ is large. How do I sample these random variables given the PDF. Do I need to calculate the mean and variance of $Y$ and then draw these $X$'s from a normal distribution with $\mu_{Y}$ and $\sigma_{Y}^{2}$. I would like to implement this into Python.

Btw. I have tried to integrate $p(x)$ to get its CDF and then use the inverse method, but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: You may need to use a numerical method to sample via the CDF, i.e., sample uniformly from $(0, 1)$ (call this $Z$) then numerically solve $Z = 1 - (x+1)e^{-x}$ for $x$ (the RHS is the CDF of your random variable).

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot that fact that I can just use numerical methods. One question: why is the 1 on the RHS is it because of RHS = P(Y <= g) = 1 - P(Y > g) = 1 - F(g)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you would have to numerically invert the cdf as described in comments, but the specific pdf of $xe^{-x}$ gives the [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) with shape parameter $k=\alpha=2$. This distribution has the nice property that the sum of *same-scale* (including iid) random variables is also gamma-distributed:
$$\sum_i\Gamma(k_i,\theta)\sim\Gamma\left(\sum_ik_i,\theta\right)$$
So your $Y$, being the sum of $n$ iid $\Gamma(2,1)$ variables, is $\Gamma(2n,1)$ distributed. Then you can calculate $P(Y>\gamma)$ from there.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer helped a lot in realising some stuff!